# Is it possible to have an animated drawable?

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, drawable

Is it possible to create a drawable that has some sort of animation, whether it is a frame by frame animation, rotation, etc, that is defined as a xml drawable and can be represented by a single Drawable object without having to deal with the animation in code?

How I am thinking to use it:
I have a list and each item in this list may at sometime have something happening to it.  While it is happening, I would like to have a spinning progress animation similar to a indeterminate ProgressBar.  Since there may also be several of these on screen I thought that if they all shared the same Drawable they would only need one instance of it in memory and their animations would be synced so you wouldn't have a bunch of spinning objects in various points in the spinning animation.

I'm not attached to this approach.  I'm just trying to think of the most efficient way to display several spinning progress animations and ideally have them synced together so they are consistent in appearance.

Thanks

**In response to Sybiam's answer:**

I have tried implementing a RotateDrawable but it is not rotating.

Here is my xml for the drawable so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable_to_rotate"
 android:fromDegrees="0" 
 android:toDegrees="360"
 android:pivotX="50%"
 android:pivotY="50%"
 android:duration="800"
 android:visible="true" />
```

I have tried using that drawable as the src and background of a ImageView and both ways only produced a non-rotating image.

Is there something that has to start the image rotation?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/30901885/1052261

Answer (score 17):

Yes! The (undocumented) key, which I discovered by reading the `ProgressBar` code is that you have to call `Drawable.setLevel()` in `onDraw()` in order for the `<rotate>` thing to have any effect. The `ProgressBar` works something like this (extra unimportant code omitted):

The drawable XML:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_outer_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="0"
             android:toDegrees="1080" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_inner_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="720"
             android:toDegrees="0" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In `onDraw()`:

```
    Drawable d = getDrawable();
    if (d != null)
    {
        // Translate canvas so a indeterminate circular progress bar with
        // padding rotates properly in its animation
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());

        long time = getDrawingTime();

        // I'm not sure about the +1.
        float prog = (float)(time % ANIM_PERIOD+1) / (float)ANIM_PERIOD; 
        int level = (int)(MAX_LEVEL * prog);
        d.setLevel(level);
        d.draw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();

        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }
```

`MAX_LEVEL` is a constant, and is always 10000 (according to the docs).
`ANIM_PERIOD` is the period of your animation in milliseconds.

Unfortunately since you need to modify `onDraw()` you can't just put this drawable in an `ImageView` since `ImageView` never changes the drawable level. However you may be able to change the drawable level from *outside* the `ImageView`'s. `ProgressBar` (ab)uses an `AlphaAnimation` to set the level. So you'd do something like this:

```
mMyImageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myDrawable, "level", 0, MAX_LEVEL);
anim.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
anim.start();
```

It might work but I haven't tested it.

## Edit

There is actually an `ImageView.setImageLevel()` method so it might be as simple as:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myImageVew, "ImageLevel", 0, MAX_LEVEL);
anim.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
anim.start();
```

Comment: Isn't there a solution that's only in XML ?

Comment: `drawable.setLevel()` is more convenient. eg:  `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawable, "level", 0, 10000)`

Comment: That's... in my answer.

Comment: @Timmmm This is not what the OP was asking for, he was specifically asking for a purely XML solution.

Comment: @LudvigW: This is as close as you can get as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

[Drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html)

There you go! And this one for [RotateDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html). I believe that from the Doc it should be pretty straitght forward. You can define everything in a xml file and set the background of a view as the drawable xml. /drawable/myrotate.xml -> @drawable/myrotate

Edit:
This is an answer I found here.
[Drawable Rotating around its center Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805622/drawable-rotating-around-its-center-android)

Edit 2:
You are right the RotateDrawable seem broken. I don't know I tried it too. I haven't yet succeded in making it animate. But I did succed to rotate it. You have to use setLevel which will rotate it. Though it doesn't look really useful. I browsed the code and the RotateDrawable doesn't even inflate the animation duration and the current rotation seems strangely use the level as a measure for rotation.  I believe you have to use it with a AnimationDrawable but here again. It just crashed for me. I haven't used that feature yet but planned to use it in the future. I browsed the web and the RotateDrawable seems to be very undocumented like almost every Drawable objects.

Comment: I tried my luck with the RotateDrawable and it did not animate.  More details up in my original question.  Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So the RotateDrawable has to be programmicatly started? I guess that kind of defeats the purpose of trying to deal with it in xml.  How would you start it?

Comment: The `RotateDrawable` is (programmatically) totally useless prior to Android API 21. You can initialize one but you cannot set its child, nor set its rotation angle. Crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of possible ways (especially useful when you have a Drawable somewhere set and need to animate it). The idea is to wrap the drawable and decorate it with animation. In my case, I had to rotate it, so below you can find sample implementation:

```
public class RotatableDrawable extends DrawableWrapper {

    private float rotation;
    private Rect bounds;
    private ObjectAnimator animator;
    private long defaultAnimationDuration;

    public RotatableDrawable(Resources resources, Drawable drawable) {
        super(vectorToBitmapDrawableIfNeeded(resources, drawable));
        bounds = new Rect();
        defaultAnimationDuration = resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        copyBounds(bounds);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(rotation, bounds.centerX(), bounds.centerY());
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    public void rotate(float degrees) {
        rotate(degrees, defaultAnimationDuration);
    }

    public void rotate(float degrees, long millis) {
        if (null != animator && animator.isStarted()) {
            animator.end();
        } else if (null == animator) {
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "rotation", 0, 0);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        }
        animator.setFloatValues(rotation, degrees);
        animator.setDuration(millis).start();
    }

    @AnimatorSetter
    public void setRotation(float degrees) {
        this.rotation = degrees % 360;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    /**
     * Workaround for issues related to vector drawables rotation and scaling:
     * https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192413
     * https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208453
     */
    private static Drawable vectorToBitmapDrawableIfNeeded(Resources resources, Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(c);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, b);
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

and you can use it like this (rotating toolbar navigation icon 360 degrees):

```
backIcon = new RotatableDrawable(getResources(), toolbar.getNavigationIcon().mutate());
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(backIcon);
backIcon.rotate(360);
```

It shouldn't be hard to add a method that will rotate it indefinite (`setRepeatMode INFINITE for animator`)

Comment: What is @AnimatorSetter it doesn't compile with it.

Comment: instanceof VectorDrawable causes crash on pre-Lollipop and not needed unless it is vector.

Comment: Also this class will need to be kept in ProGuard.

Comment: @SteveM you can use the following check to support pre Lollipop (drawable instanceof VectorDrawableCompat || drawable.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("VectorDrawable")) insteado (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable)
AnimatorSetter is my custom annotation that I use to indicate to ProGuard and Android studio that the method should be kept as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from studying the [ProgressBar2](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ProgressBar2.html) from API Demos project (it is available as a part of the SDK). Specifically pay attention to `R.layout.progressbar_2`.

Answer (score 1):

I take back to life this post just to post my solution with vector drawable:

So you need 1 vector drawable in drawable resource (@drawable/ic_brush_24dp):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <group
        android:name="rotation"  <---- target name of animated-vector
        android:pivotX="12.0"
        android:pivotY="12.0"
        android:rotation="0.0">  <--- propertyName of animator
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M7,14c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3 0,1.31 -1.16,2 -2,2 0.92,1.22 2.49,2 4,2 2.21,0 4,-1.79 4,-4 0,-1.66 -1.34,-3 -3,-3zM20.71,4.63l-1.34,-1.34c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0L9,12.25 11.75,15l8.96,-8.96c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.02 0,-1.41z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Then you need your animator in animator resource folder (@animator/pendulum)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="350"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="-90.0" />
</set>
```

Then you need your animated-vector in drawable resource (@drawable/test_anim_brush2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_brush_24dp">
    <target
        android:name="rotation"
        android:animation="@animator/pendulum" />
</animated-vector>
```

Then you need to extend ImageView (because that's the only way i found to start the animation)

```
public class ImageView extends AppCompatImageView{
    public ImageView(Context context){
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }
    public ImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    public ImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){

    }
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow(){
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Drawable d = getBackground();
    if(d instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable){
        AnimatedVectorDrawable anim = (AnimatedVectorDrawable)d;
        anim.start(); 
    }        
}
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow(){
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    Drawable d = getBackground();
    if(d instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable){
        AnimatedVectorDrawable anim = (AnimatedVectorDrawable)d;
        anim.stop();
    }
}
}
```

And then add your imageView to your layout :

```
    <ui.component.ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_anim_brush"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/test_anim_brush2"/>
```

Pro :

- You can fully define your animation in xml with object animator (duration, interpolator, etc...)
- Works with everything which accept drawable (as long as you add at good place the start animator)

Con:

- Works only with vector
- Still need to add your custom start by extending class or whenever you think it is smart...

Answer (score 0):

```
private ValueAnimator rotateDrawable(RotateDrawable drawable, int fromDegree, int toDegree) {
    drawable.setFromDegrees(fromDegree);
    drawable.setToDegrees(toDegree);
    return ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawable, "level", 0, 10000);
}
```

level is the interpulting value from 0 to 100000. the actual animation values are set by the setter methods

Answer (score 0):

> you can use stateListAnimator

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_id"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/bounce" />
```

> and bounce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce">
    <translate
        android:duration="900"

        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```