# How Do I Use 'RotateDrawable'?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Could anyone tell me how they have got `RotateDrawable` to work whether it be from code or XML or both? The documentation on animating Drawables is pretty poor and animation only seems to work for images. I want to be able to animate all drawables. When i tried to get a `RotateDrawble` from XML is just causes an exception. What is the correct function to find a `RotateDrawable` from XML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763103/rotating-a-drawable-in-android

Comment: i don't understand the question. do you want to have an animation, or just rotate the image within? for rotation, check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21376008/878126

Answer (score 19):

here's a nice solution for putting a rotated drawable for an imageView:

```
Drawable getRotateDrawable(final Bitmap b, final float angle) {
    final BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b) {
        @Override
        public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(angle, b.getWidth() / 2, b.getHeight() / 2);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    };
    return drawable;
}
```

usage:

```
Bitmap b=...
float angle=...
final Drawable rotatedDrawable = getRotateDrawable(b,angle);
root.setImageDrawable(rotatedDrawable);
```

another alternative:

```
private Drawable getRotateDrawable(final Drawable d, final float angle) {
    final Drawable[] arD = { d };
    return new LayerDrawable(arD) {
        @Override
        public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(angle, d.getBounds().width() / 2, d.getBounds().height() / 2);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    };
}
```

also, if you wish to rotate the bitmap, but afraid of OOM, you can use an NDK solution i've made [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images)

Answer (score 12):

You have to animate the "level" property, where 0 is the start value and 10000 is the end value.

The below example animates from start to finish, you can reverse the animation easily with this method.

```
final RotateDrawable rotateDrawable = ...
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(rotateDrawable, "level", 0, 10000).start();
```

Comment: A good year later this information is available here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setLevel(int)

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add a full example of animating a progress icon on ImageView, it is based on Mark Hetherington answer.

So my animation looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:pivotX="50%"
                 android:pivotY="50%"
                 android:fromDegrees="0"
                 android:toDegrees="-360"
                 android:duration="100"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loop_black_24dp"
    />
```

icon comes from https://material.io/icons/

then my layout contains an ImageView as follows:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/progress_anim"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            />
```

and finally in code when I need to show animation I do:

```
    RotateDrawable rotateDrawable = ((RotateDrawable)progressImage.getBackground());
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(rotateDrawable, "level", 0, 10000);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    anim.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

RotateDrawable does not seem to be animated.  Instead, you have to use setLevel to change the rotation of the drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

And set the level will rotate the drawable:

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
final RotateDrawable drawable = (RotateDrawable)image.getDrawable();
drawable.setLevel(500);
```

Comment: I must still be missing something here.
First what are you doing with the <rotate> tag. Your not inflating it anywhere. And second I try to cast a drawable to a RotateDrawable and get the following cast exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: I guess my example assumes that there is a layout and that layout is using an ImageView with the RotateDrawable.  If you have a bitmap, the RotateDrawable references it, not the layout.

Comment: How do you set how fast the animation is? I've tried various values for "duration", but it doesn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 3):

The following code returns a Drawable wrapper that rotates another Drawable programmatically:

```
Drawable rotateDrawable(Drawable d, final float angle) {
    // Use LayerDrawable, because it's simpler than RotateDrawable.
    Drawable[] arD = {
        d
    };
    return new LayerDrawable(arD) {
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(angle);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: you forgot to set the pivot on the rotate() function. here's a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21376008/878126

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with a RotateDrawable, but if you're simply trying to animate rotation on a graphic, you don't need it. Drawables with a 'level' like RotateDrawable are meant to convey information rather than animate views.

The following code rotates an ImageView around its center:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);

AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animSet.setFillAfter(true);
animSet.setFillEnabled(true);

final RotateAnimation animRotate = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, -90.0f,
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

animRotate.setDuration(1500);
animRotate.setFillAfter(true);
animSet.addAnimation(animRotate);

myImageView.startAnimation(animSet);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. If I understand your method correctly, this rotates the WHOLE view whereas I'd ultimately like to be able to rotate/animate a single Drawable in a view for example a pointer rotates over a background which is fixed as it is the scale for a dial. This is why I'm trying to use the RotateDrawable but unfortunately can't understand the docs!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to use Almero's Android Gesture Detectors, I decided to do the same in order to find an appropriate solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RotateGestureDetector mRotateDetector;
    private float mRotationDegrees = 0.f;
    private static final float ROTATION_RATIO = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new RotateListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private class RotateListener extends RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
            mRotationDegrees -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
            ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            // For NineOldAndroids library only!
            ViewHelper.setRotation(v, mRotationDegrees * ROTATION_RATIO);
            // For HONEYCOMB and later only!
            v.setRotation(mRotationDegrees * ROTATION_RATIO);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for me (I'm able to rotate the ImageView with two-finger rotation gesture.
NOTE: Don't forget to chose appropriate rotation method call. I commented both of them to draw your attention.

ROTATION_RATIO is just a multiplier to speed-up a rotation response on my fingers movement.
You can use any rotation axis (setRotation(), setRotationX() and setRotationY()) methods for a View.

To enable support of this code on Android devices with API Level lower than 11 (pre-Honeycomb devices) you may want to engage NineOldAndroid library.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually call RotatedDrawable.setLevel() to rotate the drawable, or you could read the code of ProgressBar, the indeterminate drawable is a LayerDrawable whose children were RotatedDrawable, like this one:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_outer_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="0"
             android:toDegrees="1080" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_inner_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="720"
             android:toDegrees="0" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The rotate animation was driven by ProgressBar's onDraw method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good working example. Param duration is used to animate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="720" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadius="20dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="4dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dp"
            android:width="48dp" />

        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="@android:color/white"
            android:startColor="#00ffffff"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate drawable forever you can use animated-rotate tag in drawable xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <animated-rotate android:drawable="@drawable/ic_refresh" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" />
    </item>
</selector>
```