# How to use RotateDrawable in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Could anyone help me how to use [RotateDrawable](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/constructor/Android.Graphics.Drawables.RotateDrawable.RotateDrawable()/) in **Xamarin**? I am working on a **Xamarin.Forms** project and I need to rotate a drawable in the **MainActivity.cs** and then set the rotated drawable as a background, I've wrote this but I got an exception:

```
RotateDrawable rotateDrawable = (RotateDrawable)Resource.Drawable.ts_logo; <<<< got exception here
Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator.OfInt(rotateDrawable, "level", 0, 10000).Start();
Window.DecorView.SetBackground(rotateDrawable);
```

The exception message is "`System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`"

Comment: I would assume your `Resource.Drawable.ts_logo` is not a `<rotate>...</rotate>` drawable....

Comment: Yes, it is not, just an image.

Comment: And I have tried `<rotate>` and `<animated-rotate>` but still get the same exception.

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you trying to achieve by animating the backgroud|view's level?

Comment: I am trying to rotate the logo in the splashscreen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Use 'RotateDrawable'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872257/how-do-i-use-rotatedrawable)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani
Not really, have a look at tags.

Comment: It's your question and you tagged it, it doesn't mean the tags are correct. if you can do something in Android (_Java_) you can do the same in Xamarin (_C#_) with small amount of changes due to language differents, so I recommend read that question and also search for Android solution.

Comment: Doesn't make sense and of course I have read this question and many others before I post a new one.
This code (my code) may be fine with java but it does make an exception with c#.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and code, Resource.Drawable.ts_logo is ID, you can not convert it to RotateDrawable.

You can try the following code:

```
RotateDrawable rotateDrawable = new RotateDrawable();
        rotateDrawable.Drawable = GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.a11);
        Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator.OfInt(rotateDrawable, "level", 0, 10000).Start();
        Window.DecorView.SetBackground(rotateDrawable);
```