# Android: ActionBar Item Animation

Tags: android, animation, action, android-actionbar

I want to apply a rotate Animation to an action in my `ActionBar`. For the `ActionBar` I´m using ActionBarSherlock.

My problem is, that in all Solutions I found (e.g. [Animated Icon for ActionItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731602/animated-icon-for-actionitem))
they are getting the `MenuItem` which shall be animated in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.

But I want to be able to start the animation even BEFORE some action is selected.
So how can I get the `MenuItem`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `findItem()` on the `Menu` supplied to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: The problem is onCreateOptionsMenu() ist called AFTER onCreate. But the Thread which starts the animation and started in onCreate is faster than onCreateOptionsMenu. 
So is there an other solution?

Comment: You can't animate something that's not there. Even if onCreateOptionsMenu() is called after onCreate() (is that contract true in all cases?), your Menu hasn't been inflated, and so there are no MenuItems to animate.

Mark's solution is correct.

Comment: @anonymous: Start your thread in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Nobody is forcing you to start it in `onCreate()`.

Comment: is it possible to animate actionBar's app logo?