# ActionBar Navigation Drawer icon on the Right side

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to show the action bar navigation icon on the Right side of the ActionBar [instead of the default left side].

Also I need to have the same slide in animation of the **Navigation Drawer icon as in the Gmail and Google plus application.**

Is there any way of achieving that animation on the right side easily.

Any kind of help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for that u have to use action-bar sherlock library

Comment: any link or source code would be helpful..

Comment: this is clear and good tuterial 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464416/use-custom-layout-in-navigationdrawer-with-header-and-list/33464417#33464417

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is how I've implemented the right navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547277/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-to-be-opened-from-right-to-left).  Just need to open and close the drawer based on Gravity.  In this example they use `Gravity.RIGHT`, I use `Gravity.END`.  I'm not sure which one is right or wrong.  Hope this helps.

This link for [ActionBar animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898972/android-actionbar-item-animation) provides some good information, and should give a good base for doing the navigation drawer icon animation.

Comment: i need to animate the navigation drawer ICON. 
The navigation drawer icon moving slightly outside the boundaries of the action bar.

Comment: My apologies for not completely answering your question, I didn't see the 'icon' portion.  This link might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898972/android-actionbar-item-animation

Comment: this is clear and good tuterial 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464416/use-custom-layout-in-navigationdrawer-with-header-and-list/33464417#33464417