# How to make a animation icon on the ActionBar?

Tags: android

I am try to make a refresh icon rotating in the actionbar of the android application.
I tried to follow this instruction:
http://techiedreams.com/android-rss-reader-part-3-action-bar-with-animated-item/

It works if I copy the code exactly the same in the website.
However, If I move it to the onCreate part, The rotation will looks different and strange.
The center of rotation seems moved to the top left corner of the view.

How can I make the icon of menu item rotate in the ActionBar normally?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animated Icon for ActionItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731602/animated-icon-for-actionitem)

Comment: @SubinSebastian I am not using sherlock actionbar...

Comment: But the answer applies to native Actionbar as well :) So give it a try first and then comment.

Comment: @SubinSebastian I tried, It doesn't work, The icon keep rotating by the top left corner of the icon..

Comment: Ok, do you mind adding your XML code for the **view** and the **animation**, and update your question?

Comment: @SubinSebastian solved, I solved it by adding a Linear Layout and put the ImageView inside, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem until i replaced the showAsAction property

Make sure to replace the refresh icon's
android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
with 
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

However it could be something else for you.