# Animated menu item "jumps" when animation starts

Tags: android, android-animation, menuitem

I am using the code from this question: [Animated Icon for ActionItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731602/animated-icon-for-actionitem) to animate my refresh `ActionBarButton`. It works fine, except that the style doesn't seem to be right. When I click the item, it starts rotating, but only after it "jumps" a few pixels. It seems like the style of the `ImageView` is different from the style of the menu item.

The item is defined like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

    <!-- added this myself, didn't have any effect -->
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"  
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>
```

and the `ImageView` like this:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_refresh"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton" />
```

How can I style my menuitem to match the `ImageView` in the rotation, or the other way round?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution by setting the `View` also for the non-animated item to be the same. In the `menu.xml`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/refresh_action_view"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>
```

Then, in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, I fetch the view in a member variable, and attach an onclick handler:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.orders, menu);
    final Menu m = menu;
    refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    refreshItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {   
                        m.performIdentifierAction(refreshItem.getItemId(), 0);
                    }
            });
    return true;
}
```

In `onCreate`, we load the animation:

```
    rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.clockwise_refresh);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Finally, call this to start the animation:

```
refreshItem.getActionView().startAnimation(rotation);
```

and this to stop it:

```
refreshItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
```

Comment: `getActionView()` is returning null for me

Comment: what is refresh_action_view layout where i define this layout

Comment: @Zapnologica Make sure to set an action view before you try to get one.

Comment: Above code did not work for me either as @Zapnologica pointed out - `getActionView()` returned null for me as well. It took me a while to realize to understand what needs to be done, so here it is:

`View image = findViewById(R.id.action_refresh); // Replace the ID with your image's one
refreshItem.setActionView(image);`

Answer (score 1):

It's better to change the ImageView to an ImageButton, and not to change the layout on the menu item in menu.xml, then the image will not jump, and you also don't need to add the click handler. It will also be the correct size, which will not be the case if you use an ImageView instead of an ImageButton.

This is all you need:

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/action_refresh"
android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
android:id="@+id/refresh_view"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Put some padding in ImageView. In my case, 8dp on each side.

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_important" />
```