# Animate MenuItem on onPrepareOptionsMenu

Tags: android

I am changing the ActionBar MenuItems in Runtime and everything is working fine, but i noticed that in Gmail for example when the ImageView is clicked (in a row) the ActionBar MenuItems have a kind of animation (flip) when loaded/changed.

currently, i am changing the ActionBar items the following way:

first i call `ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(TaskListAndOptionsActivity.activityContext);`

```
 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  //MENU
    {
if (ArrayAdapterItem.ArrayOfTasksClicked.size() > 0)
        {
            menu.clear();

  menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.accept_selected, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.accept_selected_task)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_acceptwhite)
                        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.show_selected_on_map, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.show_selected_tasks_on_map)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_directions)
                        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.remove_selections, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.remove_selected_tasks)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_removewhite)
                        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.select_all, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.remove_selected_tasks)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_select_all)
                        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);


 return  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

So the question is how to add animation to the MenuItems when they are added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19225651/1697047

Comment: thank you Sree, i saw this answer but raised the question again because maybe there is a better solution now

Comment: i don't want to set an ActionView for each MenuItem, so is there an easier way?