# Android action bar refresh animation - Repeated icon

Tags: android, xml

I follow the answer from this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9732235/2240409)

But I get this on my app:

[image]

As you can see on the ActionBar's right side there are two refresh icons (they were actually rotating when I took the screenshot). But I just want one to be there. I'm quite sure the problem is one of them is the item from the Menu XML file and the other is the ImageView from the `actionbar_inderterminate_progress.xml` file.

Here is my menu.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.mypackage.android.design.appdesgin.MainActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="Search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
      android:visible="false" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_create_local_backup"
      android:title="Search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:visible="false" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Refresh">
</item>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

And here is my `actionbar_inderterminate_progress.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/indeterminate_progress"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh" />
```

My animation XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="1000"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" />
```

And my java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
        refreshItem = item;
        refresh();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void refresh() {
     /* Attach a rotating ImageView to the refresh item as an ActionView */
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_button, null);

     Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.rotate_refresh);
     rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
     imageView.startAnimation(rotation);

     refreshItem.setActionView(imageView);
}
```

Can anyone point me where and what am I doing wrong to make it only display **one** animated refresh button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inflating the refresh button two times, one in MyActivity class and the other one on the Fragment that requires the refresh button.