# Hide menu which is created in acitivity?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have one activity with 3 fragments. I want to hide menu which is created in activity and show the fragment 2 alone.

I know how to hide menu which is created by other fragments. Is it possible to hide the Activity menu on fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you override `onCreateOptionsMenu` you can clear the menu from there.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}
```

Comment: i will try and let u know

Comment: ya it helped me ,btw is it possible to animate on action bar while chaging menus by clearing default one and creating a new one for fragment....

Comment: You can animate them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731602/animated-icon-for-actionitem but instead of rotating them you could make them fade out or something like that.