# How to animate toolbar overflow menu icon

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-menu

Is there a way to animate the default 3-vertical-dotted menu icon on toolbar?

I use toolbar as actionbar with the standard code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and I also use the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method inside activity where I inflate my `menu.xml` file
but I don't know how to gain more control over the overflow icon which is created automatically. What I'm most interested in is how to reference the menu icon So I can animate it. I don't care about the animation type. It can be a simple rotation animation

Comment: what kind of animation you're trying to do there...?

Comment: I don't care. It can be a simple rotation animation

Comment: well... use SOF search function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731602/animated-icon-for-actionitem

Comment: Yes but the overflow icon is created on its own when I inflate the `menu.xml` How can I create a reference to it? So I can animate it?

Comment: I tried to find Android actual source code of `ActionBar#addOnMenuVisibilityListener`, because I believe the method references the overflow menu button. This is an option, but maybe you will have to create your own implementation of an ActionBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you play with the `View` specifically [**`ActionMenuView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ActionMenuView.html) so try this, copy the codes into your `Activity`

```
//we declare our objects globally
Toolbar tool;  ActionMenuView amv;
```

then override `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, what you decide to `return` is your choice

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //to be safe you can check if children are greater than 1
    amv = (ActionMenuView) tool.getChildAt(1);//hope you've met amv
    return true;
}
```

now this is the crucial part- whenever you want to animate the "*3 verticall dots*" -(your overflow) you have to check visible children-(i.e if you want to) *actually forget that*

```
amv.getChildAt(amv.getChildCount()-1).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
        MainActivity.this,R.anim.abc_fade_in));
```

that gives you a basic fade-in animation- you can *pimp your ride* now.

**EDIT 1**:

The above code made assumptions that you have nothing added to your Toolbar aside from just inflating the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Suppose you have a complex `ToolBar` use this rather for your initialisation

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    for(int i =0; i < tool.getChildCount(); ++i){
        if(tool.getChildAt(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ActionMenuView")){
            amv = (ActionMenuView) tool.getChildAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**A**lso where you call your initialisation of `amv` View can be in either `onCreateOptionsMenu` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, i chose `onPrepareOptionsMenu` because i wanted readability

Hope it helps

Comment: That's actually pretty neat! I will have to check that in practice and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: well you can always accept and upvote & attach bounty to it and you are welcome@ThanosF

Comment: initialization of amv using the first way `tool.getChildAt(1);` caused classCastException but that's only because there was also a burger icon for the navigation drawer on my toolbar. Your second edited way worked wonderfully and I believe this is the right approach for initializing the `ActionMenuView` Anyways  thanks again and here is your bounty!

Comment: you are welcomed, you shouldn't have attached the bounty immediately, now its off the featured list,lol, nevermind its good, yes the second approach is the deal, the first one was the logic. @ThanosF